# $.isArray() some misunderstanding. jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to check is `p` array or not. Am I trying to check true or where am i my making mistake. Actually now i'm learning [**jQuery.isArray**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/).
I think I make mistake in my code but i do not know where. Thank you

```
var p = ['foo',''];

if(!$(p).isArray()){
  alert('no');
}else{
  alert('yes');
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tuxsanov/eEgv5/)

Comment: `$.isArray` is an utility function and not a dom element method and they should be used as @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy demonstrated in his answer. The way you used is for dom elements method such as `on`, `hide`, `remove`, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass that array as a parameter in to the `$.isArray()` function.

Try,

```
if(!$.isArray(p)){
  alert('no');
}else{
  alert('yes');
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eEgv5/1/)